# Extract id's as a list from python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I am trying to extract id's from a nested dictionary using python,
However it runs error when I run the next code:

```
nested_dictionary = {
    "name": "field",
    "vacant": "capable",
    "employees": 
        {
            1: {"id": 1, "name": "Joe", "px": "px1"},
            2: {"id": 2, "name": "Mary", "px": "px2"},
            3: {"id": 3, "name": "George", "px": "px3"},
            4: {"id": 4, "name": "Louise", "px": "px4"},
            5: {"id": 5, "name": "Malcolm", "px": "px5"},
            6: {"id": 6, "name": "Reese", "px": "px6"},
        },
        "columns": 
        [
            "col1",
            "col2",
            "col3",
            "col4"
       
        ],
    "columns_2": 
        [
            "col5",
            "col6",
            "col7"
        ]
}


for p in nested_dictionary['employees']
    print('id:' + p['id'])
```

Console Output:

```
Type Error: i object is not subscriptable
```

Expected Output:

```
id: 1
id: 2
id: 3
id: 4
id: 5
id: 6
```

Is there any other way to accomplish this task?

Comment: `print('id:' + str(nested_dictionary['employees'][p]['id']))`, each `p` represents the `key` of each employee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate over the values of the dictionary:

```
for p in nested_dictionary['employees'].values():
    print(f'id: {p["id"]}')
```

**Output**

```
id: 1
id: 2
id: 3
id: 4
id: 5
id: 6
```

Currently you are iterating over the keys. Also note that:

```
'id:' + p['id']
```

is an invalid operation because there are a *string* and *int* respectively. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) on dictionaries for more information. Also this [resource](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) for looping techniques over a dictionary.